# How to query with 2 conditions? CamlQuery

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, caml-query

I have the following 2 queries: first one is this-

1)

```
@"<Where>
  <Eq>
   <FieldRef Name='ReportsTo' />
   <Value Type='Text'>" + reportsTo + @"</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>"
```

And the second one is this:

2)

```
@"<Where>
   <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='Team' />
    <Value Type='Text'>"+ selected+ @"</Value>
   </Eq>
 </Where>";
```

How Can I merge these two queries in just one Query.

Please help me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to compare with both conditions than use **AND**:

```
@"<Where>
 <And>
  <Eq>
   <FieldRef Name='ReportsTo' />
   <Value Type='Text'>" + reportsTo + @"</Value>
  </Eq>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='Team' />
    <Value Type='Text'>"+ selected+ @"</Value>
   </Eq>
 </And>
</Where>";
```

If you want to compare with one of the conditions in query than use **OR**:

```
@"<Where>
 <Or>
  <Eq>
   <FieldRef Name='ReportsTo' />
   <Value Type='Text'>" + reportsTo + @"</Value>
  </Eq>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='Team' />
    <Value Type='Text'>"+ selected+ @"</Value>
   </Eq>
 </Or>
</Where>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your conditions in <And>...</And> inside <Where>

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms196939.aspx

```
@"<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='ReportsTo' />
            <Value Type='Text'>" + reportsTo + @"</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Team' />
            <Value Type='Text'>"+ selected+ @"</Value>
        </Eq>
    </And>
</Where>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
@"<Where>
<And>
  <Eq>
   <FieldRef Name='ReportsTo' />
   <Value Type='Text'>" + reportsTo + @"</Value>
  </Eq>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='Team' />
    <Value Type='Text'>"+ selected+ @"</Value>
   </Eq>
</And>
</Where>"
```

**NOTE:** You can also use `<Or>` tag also for or condition instead of `<And>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
@"<Where>
    <And>
      <Eq><FieldRef Name='ReportsTo' /><Value Type='Text'>" + reportsTo + @"</Value></Eq>
      <Eq><FieldRef Name='Team' /><Value Type='Text'>"+ selected+ @"</Value></Eq>
   </And>
</Where>"
```